# Listen any key pressed on edittext

Tags: java, android

I am having a question, how to handle `EditText` when I press any key from mobile, then a `Toast` will appear with its content: "Key is pressed".

I used:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {         
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        while(event.getCharacters()!=null )
                ........
        }
});
```

but it is not ok.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is my function on my application,when i entered a text in edittext field and entered,then Toast will appear with the entered content:

```
private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(){
    Bitmap bm1 = null;
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;

    try {
        bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                 getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));

        Config config = bm1.getConfig();
        if(config == null){
            config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), config);
        Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

        newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

        String captionString = editTextCaption.getText().toString();
        editTextCaption.getText().clear();
        if(captionString != null){

            Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paintText.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paintText.setTextSize(50);
            paintText.setStyle(Style.FILL);
            paintText.setShadowLayer(10f, 10f, 10f, Color.BLACK);

            Rect rectText = new Rect();
            paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), rectText);

            newCanvas.drawText(captionString, 0, rectText.height(), paintText);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawText: " + captionString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "caption empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

OR use it on this way hope it's help:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {         
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    while(event.getCharacters()!=null )
            String captionString = edittext.getText().toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawText: " + captionString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

i put the comments but it's not show,i don't know why,ok try this hope it's worked,also it's working fine on my side.

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {         
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    while(event.getCharacters()!=null )
            String captionString = edittext.getText().toString();
if(captionString != null){
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawText: " + captionString,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "caption empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i used the second suggestion but it didn't work on my mobile. when i press key on my mobile , it isn't appear Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following ---

```
 edittext.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                   //Do anything with editTextContent
                   String editTextContent = edittext.getText().toString();

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   editTextContent +": Key is pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    });
```

Comment: hey guy, I runned but it had a problem. Can u check code for me? Thanks.

Comment: @giangdaughtry - what was the problem/error ? What's your code ?

Comment: my mobile appear "... don't responese, do you want to wait ?"